# Invoking a function before destroying popup pausing it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a popup window as such:

```
def save():
  time.sleep(5) #assuming task takes 5 seconds 

def cancel_pop(popup,callback=None):
  popup.destroy()

  if(callback!=None)
    callback()

def show_popup_settings():

   popup=Toplevel(root)

   ...

   popup.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda: cancel_pop(popup,lambda: save()))
```

but invoking the `callback()` somehow cause `destroy()` to pause
how do I fix this?

Comment: by not sleeping the entire thread... you could call `root.update` after that `destroy` call which will remove the popup, still the thread would sleep for 5 seconds, also just `lambda: cancel_pop(pop, save)`

Comment: There are few typos: `call_back=None` should be `callback=None`, `popup.destory()` should be `popup.destroy()`, `cancel_pop(pop,...)` should be `cancel_pop(popup,...)`, etc. Also cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.13.

Comment: @acw1668 my apologies I wrote this in a hurry, I've corrected them now

Comment: @Matiiss ah yes! just the magic I needed, could you post this as an answer so I can mark as correct?